# Javascript screenscraper

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, css-selectors, screen-scraping

I am trying to make a simple screen scraper on this site - [List of Javascript libraries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) it should be run through console and return all the libraries as text without categories. I managed to get all of them with code below. They also mentioned we can use a map() function for mapping the contents however I was unable to do that. My question is how to loop through all the categories and concatenate various arrays into one single array of library names? Any help appreciated!

```
root = document.documentElement
const firstTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[0]
const firstGroup = firstTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const secondTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[1]
const secondGroup = secondTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const thirdTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[2]
const thirdGroup = thirdTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const fourthTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[3]
const fourthGroup = fourthTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const fifthTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[4]
const fifthGroup = fifthTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const sixthTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[5]
const sixthGroup = sixthTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const seventhTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[6]
const seventhGroup = seventhTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const eightTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[7]
const eightGroup = eightTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent
const ninthTitle = root.getElementsByClassName("mw-headline")[8]
const ninthGroup = secondTitle.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent

Array(firstGroup, secondGroup, thirdGroup, fourthGroup, fifthGroup, sixthGroup, seventhGroup, eightGroup, ninthGroup)
```

RESULT

```
(9) ["↵Cassowary (software)↵CHR.js↵", "↵Google Polymer↵Dojo Toolkit↵jQuery↵midori↵MooTools↵Prototype JavaScript Framework↵", "↵See also: List of JavaScript graphics libraries↵A…echart↵Three.js↵Velocity.js↵Verge3D↵WhitestormJS↵", "↵AngularJS (framework)↵Angular (application platfo…K↵Glow↵Lively Kernel↵Script.aculo.us↵YUI Library↵", "Ample SDK↵Glow↵Lively Kernel↵Script.aculo.us↵YUI Library↵", "↵Google Closure Library↵Joose↵JsPHP↵Microsoft's Aj…F.js↵Rico↵Socket.IO↵Spry framework↵Underscore.js↵", "↵Cascade Framework↵jQuery Mobile↵Mustache↵Jinja-JS↵Twig.js↵", "↵Jasmine↵Mocha↵QUnit↵Tape↵Unit.js↵", "↵Google Polymer↵Dojo Toolkit↵jQuery↵midori↵MooTools↵Prototype JavaScript Framework↵"]
0
:
"↵Cassowary (software)↵CHR.js↵"
1
:
"↵Google Polymer↵Dojo Toolkit↵jQuery↵midori↵MooTools↵Prototype JavaScript Framework↵"
2
:
"↵See also: List of JavaScript graphics libraries↵AnyChart↵D3.js↵FusionCharts↵Highcharts↵EaselJS, part of CreateJS↵JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit↵p5.js↵Pixi.js↵Plotly↵Processing.js↵Raphaël↵SWFObject↵Teechart↵Three.js↵Velocity.js↵Verge3D↵WhitestormJS↵"
3
:
"↵AngularJS (framework)↵Angular (application platform)↵Bootstrap↵DevExtreme of DevExpress↵DHTMLX↵Dojo Widgets↵Ext JS of Sencha↵ZURB Foundation↵Google's Polymer paper elements↵jQuery UI↵jQWidgets↵Ignite UI of Infragistics↵Kendo UI of Telerik↵Wijmo 5 of GrapeCity↵OpenUI5 of SAP↵qooxdoo↵SmartClient↵React.js↵Webix↵WinJS↵No longer actively developedEdit↵Ample SDK↵Glow↵Lively Kernel↵Script.aculo.us↵YUI Library↵"
4
:
"Ample SDK↵Glow↵Lively Kernel↵Script.aculo.us↵YUI Library↵"
5
:
"↵Google Closure Library↵Joose↵JsPHP↵Microsoft's Ajax library↵MochiKit↵PDF.js↵Rico↵Socket.IO↵Spry framework↵Underscore.js↵"
6
:
"↵Cascade Framework↵jQuery Mobile↵Mustache↵Jinja-JS↵Twig.js↵"
7
:
"↵Jasmine↵Mocha↵QUnit↵Tape↵Unit.js↵"
8
:
"↵Google Polymer↵Dojo Toolkit↵jQuery↵midori↵MooTools↵Prototype JavaScript Framework↵"
length
:
9
```

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="mf-section"] li>a:first-of-type:not(.external)')].map(a => [a.closest('li').textContent, a.href]).join('\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used querySelector to find all the nodes of the categories names:
Here's a working example tested :

```
const libNames = [... document.documentElement.querySelectorAll('.mw-headline')].map((lib) => lib.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent)
```

if you want a single string you can join libNames :

```
const libNames = [... document.documentElement.querySelectorAll('.mw-headline')].map((lib) => lib.nextElementSibling.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent).join(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Do you think it's also possible to concatenate those to make one single array?

Comment: libNames is an Array !! do you mean a single string ?

Comment: Nope sorry, I am just stupid! I thought it's an array of arrays. I've been onto this for couple of hours and my brain is fried. as a UX designer in front-end class it gives me hell.